# C++: alias or initialize a value

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have a template type, `A`, with two instantiations `A<X>` and `A<Y>`.

Suppose I have a template function that asserts the template type is of type `A` (either `A<X>` or `A<Y>`).

Further, suppose that I can interchange between the two types with the assignment operator:

```
// given A<X> a, 
A<Y> ay = a; // <-- assignment converts the item
```

---

Is there a way I can do the following (written in pseudo code):

```
// given A<Y> a, template type name Atype

A<Y> ay = std::is_base_of<A<Y>,Atype>::value ? alias(a) : a;
```

where `alias(a)` creates some kind of alias--like a reference or a pointer, and does not require copying or otherwise running the entire assignment operation.

---

```
struct left{};
struct right{};

template<typename dir>
struct A{};

template<typename Atype>
function(Atype a){
    // assert Atype is either of 
    // A<left> or A<right>

    if(std::is_base_of<A<left>,Atype>::value)
        do_this(a);
    else{
        A<left> al = a; // <-- 3rd party library, O(sizeof(a)) operation, so necessary to check
        do_this(al);
    }
}
```

All I am trying to do is remove the if statement, because it is a highly repetitive (i.e., ugly) structure in my code. Would like to replace it with a function, but am finding it very difficult.

Comment: You might get somebody to answer your question if you post a [mcve].

Comment: What is a "subtype"?

Comment: @bordeo Please don't invent terminology. Even after your explanation I still don't know what a "subtype" is.

Comment: @liliscent it is not jargon, it is a description.

Comment: Does `A<left>` have a move constructor?

Comment: @melpomene you are right. TBH, I have no idea how the lib guys did it.

Comment: @melpomene I will try to find out.

Comment: @melpomene the ide isn't finding anything, and I don't see anything in the source

Answer (score 0):

For now, I am executing the following:

```
template<typename InClass,typename OutClass>
OutClass & move_or_assign(InClass & ic){
    if(std::is_base_of<OutClass,InClass>::value) return ic;
    return std::move(ic);
}
```